# Assembler reports illegal mnemonics when building OpenSSL on Solaris_x86

Tags: compiler-errors, openssl, solaris

I'm building OpenSSL 1.1.1d for Solaris_x86 (5.10), but the build process fails with numerous 'illegal mnemonic' messages when attempting to build `aesni-mb-x86_64`.

Example:

```
cc -KPIC -xarch=generic64 -xstrconst -Xa -xO5 -xdepend -xbuiltin -DFILIO_H -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/testdir/openssl/1.1.1d/solaris_x86_10_64/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/testdir/openssl/1.1.1d/solaris_x86_10_64/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DNDEBUG  -c -o crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.o crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s
Assembler:
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 9 : Illegal mnemonic
    Near line: ".cfi_startproc  "
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 9 : Syntax error
    Near line: ".cfi_startproc  "
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 11 : Illegal mnemonic
    Near line: ".cfi_def_cfa_register   %rax"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 11 : Syntax error
    Near line: ".cfi_def_cfa_register   %rax"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 13 : Illegal mnemonic
    Near line: ".cfi_offset %rbx,-16"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 13 : Syntax error
    Near line: ".cfi_offset %rbx,-16"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 15 : Illegal mnemonic
    Near line: ".cfi_offset %rbp,-24"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 15 : Syntax error
    Near line: ".cfi_offset %rbp,-24"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 17 : Illegal mnemonic
    Near line: ".cfi_offset %r12,-32"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 17 : Syntax error
    Near line: ".cfi_offset %r12,-32"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 19 : Illegal mnemonic
    Near line: ".cfi_offset %r13,-40"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 19 : Syntax error
    Near line: ".cfi_offset %r13,-40"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 21 : Illegal mnemonic
    Near line: ".cfi_offset %r14,-48"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 21 : Syntax error
    Near line: ".cfi_offset %r14,-48"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 23 : Illegal mnemonic
    Near line: ".cfi_offset %r15,-56"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 23 : Syntax error
    Near line: ".cfi_offset %r15,-56"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 33 : Illegal mnemonic
    Near line: ".cfi_escape 0x0f,0x05,0x77,0x10,0x06,0x23,0x08"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 33 : Syntax error
    Near line: ".cfi_escape 0x0f,0x05,0x77,0x10,0x06,0x23,0x08"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 243 : Illegal mnemonic
    Near line: ".cfi_def_cfa    %rax,8"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 243 : Syntax error
    Near line: ".cfi_def_cfa    %rax,8"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 261 : Illegal mnemonic
    Near line: ".cfi_restore    %r15"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 261 : Syntax error
    Near line: ".cfi_restore    %r15"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 263 : Illegal mnemonic
    Near line: ".cfi_restore    %r14"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 263 : Syntax error
    Near line: ".cfi_restore    %r14"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 265 : Illegal mnemonic
    Near line: ".cfi_restore    %r13"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 265 : Syntax error
    Near line: ".cfi_restore    %r13"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 267 : Illegal mnemonic
    Near line: ".cfi_restore    %r12"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 267 : Syntax error
    Near line: ".cfi_restore    %r12"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 269 : Illegal mnemonic
    Near line: ".cfi_restore    %rbp"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 269 : Syntax error
    Near line: ".cfi_restore    %rbp"
    "crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s", line 271 : Illegal mnemonic
    Near line: ".cfi_restore    %rbx"
Too many errors - Goodbye
cc: assembler failed for crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s
```

This has worked on numerous other platforms, including rs6000 and hpia64, so I've got a fair bit of confidence in the general build process; that said, I'm neither a C/C++ developer, nor a Solaris guru, and am feeling a bit out of my depth troubleshooting this.

My first thought was, switch from Solaris' compiler to `gcc`; however, that would likely cause problems with other components which need to use OpenSSL and which were built with the native compiler.

I believe OpenSSL 1.1.x uses the Perl module `Text::Template` to format the `.s` file, so possible that module isn't doing what it should here; absent better advice, that's what I'll look into next.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: RS6000 & HPIA64 wouldn't be trying to use the AESNI instructions added to x86 CPUs in recent years - probably too new for the compiler in use.  While C code compiled by Studio & gcc are compatible, C++ generally isn't - but OpenSSL 1.1 isn't compatible with existing binaries built for OpenSSL 1.0, so you'll likely need to rebuild everything anyway.

Comment: @alanc I'm building OpenSSL new; I won't be combining binaries from 1.0 and 1.1.  
My concern with the compiler is ensuring compatibility with other compiled tools.  I don't want to switch to `gcc` to build OpenSSL and then discover my shiny new libs won't work with the existing Perl build.

Comment: @AndrewHenle it's the default compiler shipped with Solaris - `/usr/ucb/cc`

Comment: I have never seen any version of Solaris that ships with a compiler other than the GCC supplied in later Solaris versions.   As far as I know, the Sun/Oracle Sunworks/Forte/Sun ONE Studio/Sun Studio/Oracle Solaris Studio/Oracle Developer Studio has always been a  separate installation.

Comment: `/usr/ucb/cc` has never actually been a compiler in Solaris either, just a wrapper around the unbundled compilers to set some old SunOS 4 compatibility flags.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use the latest Oracle developer studio compiler, you can download this at https://www.oracle.com/tools/developerstudio/downloads/developer-studio-jsp.html

We had no success with assembly on Solaris 10 either, and we configure OpenSSL as follows:

```
 ./configure shared no-asm solaris-x86-gcc -lrt
```

The important bit here is the `no-asm` keyword that makes OpenSSL use C code instead of assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I also occur a similar issue while building on Solaris x86. After rebooting the machine and rebuilding it will back to work. Does anyone know the reason?

(I,m sorry to post my question to answer area because I don't have 50 reputation to add a comment)

```bash
00:36:16.751  "wsdlC.cpp", line 19662: Warning (Anachronism): Using int(*)(soap_clist*) to initialize extern "C" int(*)(soap_clist*).
00:36:16.751  "wsdlC.cpp", line 19749: Warning (Anachronism): Using int(*)(soap_clist*) to initialize extern "C" int(*)(soap_clist*).
00:36:16.751  "wsdlC.cpp", line 19836: Warning (Anachronism): Using int(*)(soap_clist*) to initialize extern "C" int(*)(soap_clist*).
00:36:16.751  199 Warning(s) detected.
00:36:16.751  Assembler: 
00:36:16.751    "/tmp/ube.1668675213.12464.06.s", line 1 : Syntax error
00:36:16.751    Near line: "581.51809"
00:36:16.751    "/tmp/ube.1668675213.12464.06.s", line 98 : Outside cfi coderange
00:36:16.751    "/tmp/ube.1668675213.12464.06.s", line 389 : Illegal mnemonic
00:36:16.751    Near line: "    .alig"
00:36:16.751    "/tmp/ube.1668675213.12464.06.s", line 389 : Syntax error
00:36:16.751    Near line: "    .alig"
00:36:16.751    "/tmp/ube.1668675213.12464.06.s", line 99 : Illegal subtraction in ... ".DOT_0 - __1cH__rwstdJ__rb_tree4CpkcC2n0AH__ident4C2C2__nFltstr_nDstdJallocator4C2___Ferase6Mn0FIiterator__5_"
00:36:16.751  CC: fbe failed for wsdlC.cpp
00:36:16.751  gmake[3]: *** [/workspace/build/src/x64release/objs/thirdparty/gsoap/wsdl/wsdlC.o] Error 2
00:36:16.751  gmake[2]: *** [execs] Error 2
00:36:16.751  gmake[1]: *** [execs] Error 2
00:36:16.751  gmake: *** [execs] Error 2
00:36:16.751  SMM stopped successfully.
```